# How to set focus to Inbox?

Tags: vba, outlook

When you open Outlook, Inbox has the focus. If you go to another folder then run VBA code the focus stays on that folder.

My macro deletes all files in my Deleted folder and Trash folder. I would like it to come back to the Inbox when complete.

```vb
Public Sub EmptyFolder()
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim Delete As Boolean
    ' Clear Junk Items
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Parent.Folders("Junk").Items
    Count = Items.Count
    If Count = 0 Then
        GoTo DeleteAll
    End If
    Delete = True
    For i = Count To 1 Step -1
        Items(i).Delete
    Next
DeleteAll:
    ' Clear Trash Items
    Set Items = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Parent.Folders("Trash").Items
    Count = Items.Count
    If Count = 0 Then
        GoTo EndAll
    End If
    Delete = True
    For i = Count To 1 Step -1
        Items(i).Delete
    Next
EndAll:
    
End Sub
```

Comment: 1 Answer didn't work. Got a Run-time error '-214721233 *8004010f'): The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found. on the line set folder1 = myInbox.folders.item("Inbox")  or ("family") in your answer.

Comment: Cross-posted on *multiple* other forums, including: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?68352-How-to-get-focus-of-Outlook-folder-in-vba & https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/outlook-vba.1160128/, but refuses to provide links. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Thanks BraX.  I got it to work.  Evidently macropod is trying to blackball me on other websites because he got so nasty on his site.  Hope it doesn't affect this site.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just change the CurrentFolder value to one of your Inbox folders in my example "family" as follow.

```
Sub ChangeCurrentFolder()

Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace

Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

On a related note to what you are trying to achieve (but not directly related to the question), I use a generic function to delete older e-mails from folders and the code is below:

Call the function in Startup

> In ThisOutlookSession

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    On Error Resume Next
    Call DeleteAgedJunkMail
End Sub
```

> In a module

```
Function DeleteAgedJunkMail() As Boolean
    Dim ThisNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace: Set ThisNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Inbox = ThisNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim Junk As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Junk = ThisNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Call DeleteAgedMail(Junk, 7)
    Call DeleteAgedMail(Inbox.Folders("Quotes"), 90)
    Call DeleteAgedMail(Inbox.Folders("Orders"), 90)

    DeleteAgedJunkMail = True        
End Function

Function DeleteAgedMail(ByRef Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, Optional Days As Long = 7) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ExitFunction
     
    Dim Var As Variant, i As Long, Difference As Long, Items As Long
    For i = Folder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Var = Folder.Items.Item(i)
        DoEvents
        If Var.Class = olMail Then
            Difference = DateDiff("d", Var.SentOn, Now)
            If Difference > Days Then
                Var.Delete
                Items = Items + 1   'Count the # of items deleted
            End If
        End If
    Next
     
    ' Record the number of items that were deleted.
    Debug.Print "Deleted " & Items & " message(s) from '" & Folder.Name & "'."
    DeleteAgedMail = True
    
ExitFunction:
End Function
```